# keep page content on screen change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with two versions (desktop, mobile). I'm testing both versions on an iPad mini; the desktop version shows in landscape, the mobile shows in portrait. I have a side navigation with links that when clicked, hide and un-hide certain elements. When the page is loaded, it starts out on the 'about' section. From there, you can click on pricing and other links. When I rotate the device, I check the screen size with jQuery and load the appropriate version. But, because the page always starts at 'about', no matter which link you're on, the rotation makes the page jump back to 'about'. Is there a way to detect which content I am seeing, and make the rotation keep that content on the screen? I have a `link-active` class attached to the link that was most recently clicked. Ideally I'm looking for a jQuery answer.

jQuery to check screen size:

Desktop (change to mobile)

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  if($(window).width() <= 768) {
    window.location = "q3m.html";
  }
});
```

Mobile (change to desktop)

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  if($(window).width() > 768) {
    window.location = '/~kwilliam/Q';
  }
});
```

Making the 'about' section active on load (HTML):

```
<a id="about" class="link-active">about</a>
<a id="pricing">pricing</a>
<a id="projects">projects</a>
<a id="legal">legal</a>
```

Comment: Consider using Media Queries instead of managing a separate mobile and desktop version of your site.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did consider using media queries, however I decided against it because the mobile version uses icons, I hide the desktop version left nav inside the menu icon and it moves in from the right, there are different features for the two versions. I found it easier to maintain different files.

Comment: Hmmm, I really don't see why Media Queries was taken off the table because you use icons in the mobile version. This is exactly the kind of think Media Queries is for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've used media queries for past projects, but decided to try to maintain different versions. I'm experimenting with file managament, and just found it easier to not have to do `display: none` for things.

Comment: But, you understand that you can swap images for icons, right with media queries, right? You don't have to hide one thing and show another, you just modify the source of the elements.

Comment: Yes, but again, there are other differences that make managing two files easier for me.

Comment: You do understand that this is just really bad practice ?

Comment: Does anyone have an actual answer? Or is it impossible to somehow save the active link on rotation?